# Basic expect script issue

Tags: routing

If anyone could help me with this basic expect script because it would make my life easier as a networkin engineer.I'm not a good Linux user because i don't use it often but i need to be able to make a basic expect script.You can see underneath my simple example to use only "sh ip int br" command.I would use the same logic to enter in config mode to use other commands but my biggest problem is that i'm not able to login in to my router at all. I would highly appreciate your help.

1.I've made the script like you can see underneath

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set username elio
set password hgkjtjwowq
set host 172.16.12.254

spawn telnet $host
expect "login:"
send "$username\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "Nexus1#"
send "sh ip int br\r"
expect "Nexus1#"
send "exi\r"
expect eof
```

---

2.I've checked where is my script located

```
elio@mabu-199:~$ whereis expect
expect: /usr/bin/expect /usr/bin/X11/expect /usr/share/man/man1/expect.1.gz
```

---

3.You can see when i run the script i receive the following infosl

```
elio@mabu-199:~$ ./testscript.exp
./testscript.exp: line 8: spawn: command not found
couldn't read file "login:": no such file or directory
./testscript.exp: line 10: send: command not found
couldn't read file "Password:": no such file or directory
./testscript.exp: line 12: send: command not found
couldn't read file "Nexus1#": no such file or directory
./testscript.exp: line 14: send: command not found
couldn't read file "Nexus1#": no such file or directory
./testscript.exp: line 16: send: command not found
couldn't read file "eof": no such file or directory
```

I would appreciate your help .Thanks in advance

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to change the first line of your script, and add -f at the end. Then, it must look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
```

The -f tells to "Expect" that it will be reading commands from a file, your script.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation what is the meaning of - f but believe me i edited the first line of  my script earlier even before you said like this:  #!/usr/bin/expect -f      but the same issue  again.

Comment: Do you script have execution permision?? Try with chmod 777

Comment: Thank you Orlando ,yes my file has executiuon permision but i've fixed the issue.The name of code was not in the first line,i chnage only that and it works like a champ:) I will remove my question and say thanks to people who try to help me..

Comment: Oh, i'm glad to hear that works